# is $dx$ (at least in integrals) a positive real number?

Tags: definite-integrals

Given the Riemann integral: $\int_a^b f(x)dx$

By definition: $dx = lim \frac{b-a}n$ as $n\rightarrow+\infty$. So, is it $dx$ a real number and a positive one as it seems apparent by defintion?
There seems to be a lot of confusion in literature about what $dx$ really is and none agrees that $dx$ is just a positive real number, but I really don't know why!

Comment: It is not. It's just a symbol.

Comment: There isn't much confusion in the literature, the source of the confusion is that most ways of formalizing what $dx$ means are too technical for a basic calculus course. Anyhow, regardless of how you formalize it, $dx$ is definitely not a number.

Comment: No, it is an infinitesimal representing an infinitesimal change in the value of $x$.

Comment: I disagree with the downvote (upvoted to correct this). This was a sincere question about a confusing concept.

Comment: Note that although $\frac {b-a}n$ will be a positive real number for any *specific* $n$ the *limit* $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {b-a}n=0$ is not a positive real number.  You're definition of $dx$ is not quite correct. $dx \ne \lim \frac {b-a}n$ but $\int_a^b f(x)dx =\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0;x\in (k\Delta x,(k+1)\Delta x)} f(x)\cdot \Delta x$ where $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}n$.  $dx$ represents the *concept* of the limit of $\Delta x$ but only in *conjunction* with it being within a limit of an infinite sum. The actual limit of $\Delta x$ is $0$ and is useless by itself...tbc....

Comment: ..cont... it's kind of a little bit like $n \times \frac 1n = 1$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty} n\times \frac 1n = 0$.  If we want to express the *concept* of $\frac 1n \to 0$ we *don't* use $\lim \frac 1n$ because that's just $0$ and isn't useful.  We can't break up a product of limits like that:  $1= \lim n\times \frac 1n \ne \lim n \times \lim \frac 1n = \infty \times 0 =??????$.  But we do want the *concept* of the two parts of the limit.  $d\frac 1n$ is just what we use for the $\frac 1n$ part.

Comment: @fleablood Why to write that in a comment? You should write an answer.

Comment: Because this is probably a duplicate.  It's also fairly casual and doesn't actually *define* what $dx$ is.  It just describes what it sort of is.... I see in my comment (which I can no longer edit) that I made a typo... I meant $\lim n\times \frac 1n =1$ (not zero).

Comment: Thank you all guys for answers but would you please answer this question here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505249/work-in-elastic-force-what-sign-should-be-interpreted-for-dx

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the $dx$ symbol as just part of the integral notation. The notation makes it looks like a number, because it takes the place of the actual small positive number $\Delta x$ that appears in each of the finite Riemann sums. But these $\Delta x$ values approach 0 in the limit, so there's no actual positive number that the $dx$ represents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but would you please answer me this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505249/work-in-elastic-force-what-sign-should-be-interpreted-for-dx